# MSA30 Linux CLI Configuration?

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, scsi, hp-storageworks

Can some one help me shed some light on this please?

I have a MSA30 hooked up to a HP Proliant DL380 G4 running SuSE SLES Linux. My question is how do I configure the hard drives connected to be in a JBOD setup. Would this be with hpacucli or though some other software. I've tried using hpacucli but it does not detect the msa which I know is a work as I can seen it been detected during system boot. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a bit of information here. How is the MSA30 enclosure connected to the server? What type of controller are you connected to?

If you've connected it to a Smart Array controller (like the SmartArray 6400, 642, 5300, etc.), the disks in the array can be configured via the `hpacucli` utility or the RAID controller's BIOS utility. Otherwise, if connected to a standard SCSI HBA, the MSA30 is a dumb disk shelf. The drives would show up as individual SCSI disks in your Linux OS (`cat /proc/scsi/scsi` or look through `dmesg` or try `fdisk -l`).

The [ProLiant DL380 G4](http://h18006.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12099_na/12099_na.html#Technical%20Specifications) has an external SCSI port that may or may not be connected to the onboard SCSI controller. Are you connecting the MSA30 to a motherboard port or to a PCI card?